# How can I limit whatever Time Machine wants to do with sparsebundles

Tags: backup, time-machine, time-capsule

Is there a way to limit the "appetite" Time Machint?
How do I this is achieved in the most simple manner on a network drive?

Comment: Please edit your question to be *just* a question, then wait for it being reopened, then post the rest of the text as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As is often the question is how to limit the size of backup Time Machine, and then the subject of this post.

So:

All Time Machine backups keeps "growing image-disc package «https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file(sparsebundle)», which is the physical size at the location takes exactly as much space as occupied by the data stored in it (), while Time Machine creates backups, capturing all the available disk space (it can be seen for example in the disk utility, select your mounted * .sparsebundle and pressing the "info" button).
Even if you change the size of the * .sparsebudle, the next time you create a reserve copy of Time Machine (from version 10.6.3) again to change the size of the maximum possible.

Yet there are ways to limit the "appetite" Time Machine.

The first requires Xcode, and, in principle, interfere in the "life" Titem Machine (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2383738?start=60&tstart=45)

The second is that the limited size does not * .sparsebundle, and section (partition) with backups on it.
For this, I wrote a one-line script mentioned below (copy and paste in Terminal.app):

```
time { clear; declare -i s; read -p "The name of the mount point of your disk?" dn; read -p "Desired partition size in GB?= " s; ((sb=10**9*s/512)); cn=`scutil --get ComputerName`; echo -e "\nWait..."; hdiutil resize -size ${sb}b -partitiononly "/Volumes/${dn}/${cn}.sparsebundle" && echo -e "\n\n\t\t\e[01;38;05;40;48;05;20m"Section now has a size"${s}GB\e[0m" || echo -e "\n\n\t\t\e[01;38;05;160;48;05;20m"Alas, the partition size is not changed"\e[0m"; }
```

Means "/ Applications / Utilities / Disk Utility.app" (GUI) to change the size of the partition backups can only be a very limited extent.